# Is there a chance to replace a while loop with the TPL?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I've a two while loops, which I will have run parallel with the TPL.

My code :

```
public void Initialize()
{
   cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

   ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
   options.CancellationToken = cts.Token;
   options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount;

    task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parallel.Invoke(options, Watcher1, Watcher2), cts.Token);
}

public void Watcher1()
{
   //Can I replace this (with a TPL construct in the initialize method)?
   while(true)
   {
      //Do sth.
   }
}

public void Watcher2()
{
   //Can I replace this (with a TPL construct in the initialize method)?
   while(true)
   {
      //do sth 
   }
}
```

It would be nice, if I can cancel this two actions safely. Can you give me some advices?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards, pro

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a `CancellationTokenSource`, see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/parallel-programming-task-cancellation) for details

Answer (score 2):

```
public void Initialize()
{
   var cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
   var cancellationToken = cancellationSource.Token;

   //Start both watchers
   var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Watcher1(cancellationToken));
   var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Watcher2(cancellationToken));

   //As an example, keep running the watchers until "stop" is entered in the console window
   while (Console.Readline() != "stop")
   {
   }

   //Trigger the cancellation...
   cancellationSource.Cancel();

   //...then wait for the tasks to finish.
   Task.WaitAll(new [] { task1, task2 });
}

public void Watcher1(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
   {
      //Do stuff
   }
}

public void Watcher2(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
   {
      //Do stuff
   }
}
```